# Foreach result as row sort into different arrays based on name

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, foreach

I'm trying to get familiar with ORACLE and playing around with PHP and ORACLE..I have a table in database like this:

```
| rec_id | red   | orange |
| rec_id | yellow| orange |
| rec_id | green | apple  |
| rec_id | red   | apple  |
| rec_id | green | lime   |
| rec_id | red   | grape  |
| rec_id | red   | carrot |
```

..I need to create multidimensional array something like:

```
array
    0=>orange{
         0=>red,
         1=>yellow}
    1=>apple{
         0=>green,
         1=>red}
    2=>lime{
         0=>green}
   etc..
```

What would be the fastest and safest way to do it using `foreach($result as $row)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach should suffice. Under the loop, set `fruits` as keys then append the `colors`. Consider this example:

```
$values_from_db = array( array('rec_id' => 1, 'color' => 'red', 'fruit' => 'orange'), array('rec_id' => 2, 'color' => 'yellow', 'fruit' => 'orange'), array('rec_id' => 3, 'color' => 'green', 'fruit' => 'apple'), array('rec_id' => 4, 'color' => 'red', 'fruit' => 'apple'), array('rec_id' => 5, 'color' => 'green', 'fruit' => 'lime'), array('rec_id' => 6, 'color' => 'red', 'fruit' => 'grape'), array('rec_id' => 7, 'color' => 'red', 'fruit' => 'carrot'),);
$new_values = array();
foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[$value['fruit']][] = $value['color']; 
}
print_r($new_values);
```

Should result into something like: [**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sSCZ9A)

```
Array
(
    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => yellow
        )

    [apple] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => red
        )

    [lime] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
        )

    [grape] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
        )

    [carrot] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
        )

)
```

Comment: WoW! That's a great explanation! Perfect, just what I need! Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$out = array();
foreach($result as $row)
    $out[$row['fruit']][] = $row['color'];
}
print_r($out);

?>
```

If you need unique arrays for each of the fruits here are 2 possible ways.

```
//two loops
$out = array();
foreach($row as $r){
    $out[$r['fruit']][] = $r['color'];
}
foreach($out as $i > $o){
    $out[$i] = array_unique($o);
}
print_r($out);



//one loop
$out = array();
foreach($row as $r){
    $out[$r['fruit']] = isset($out[$r['fruit']]) ? $out[$r['fruit']] : array();
    if(!in_array($r['color'],$out[$r['fruit']])){
        $out[$r['fruit']][] = $r['color'];
    }
}
print_r($out);
```